# Firebase Acting Weird with Typecasting

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make a chatting app with firebase. In some cases, the function to retrieve the messages only returns some of the messages. I tried to find out where exactly it is breaking. I figured out that the Snapshot is always correct but while unwrapping the data the guard makes it go to the else and nil is returned only for the recipient when I use an actual iPhone, however, if I chat using two simulators everything works perfectly. I was following a youtube video so I have no idea what to do about this situation.

This is my code:

```
public func getAllMessagesForConversation(with id: String, completion: @escaping (Result<[Message], Error>) -> Void) {
    database.child("\(id)/messages").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        guard let value = snapshot.value as? [[String: Any]] else{
            completion(.failure(DatabaseError.failedToFetch))
            return
        }
        let messages: [Message] = value.compactMap({ dictionary in
            guard let name = dictionary["name"] as? String,
                  let isRead = dictionary["is_read"] as? Bool,
                  let messageID = dictionary["id"] as? String,
                  let content = dictionary["content"] as? String ,
                  let senderEmail = dictionary["sender_email"] as? String,
                  let type = dictionary["type"] as? String,
                  let dateString = dictionary["date"] as? String,
                  let date = ChatViewController.dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) else {
                  //it comes down here in some cases but the formatting of the dictionary is identical 
                  print(dictionary)
                return nil
            }
            
            let sender = Sender(senderId: senderEmail,
                                photoURL: "",
                                displayName: name)
            
            
            return Message(sender: sender,
                           messageId: messageID,
                           sentDate: date,
                           kind: .text(content))
        })
        
        completion(.success(messages))
    })
}
```

I see no difference so I am very confused that why would the guard do this.

This is the snapshot variable:

```
Snap (messages) {
    0 =     {
        content = "Hello!";
        date = "19-Dec-2020 at 7:32:18 PM IST";
        id = "devang-test-com_abha-test-com_19-Dec-2020 at 7:32:18 PM IST";
        "is_read" = 0;
        name = "Devang Agrawal";
        "sender_email" = "abha-test-com";
        type = text;
    };
    1 =     {
        content = "Hello!";
        date = "Dec 19, 2020 at 8:04:34 PM GMT+5:30";
        id = "abha-test-com_devang-test-com_Dec 19, 2020 at 8:04:34 PM GMT+5:30";
        "is_read" = 0;
        name = "Abha Agrawal";
        "sender_email" = "devang-test-com";
        type = text;
    };
    2 =     {
        content = "What is going on ?";
        date = "Dec 19, 2020 at 8:04:55 PM GMT+5:30";
        id = "abha-test-com_devang-test-com_Dec 19, 2020 at 8:04:55 PM GMT+5:30";
        "is_read" = 0;
        name = "Abha Agrawal";
        "sender_email" = "devang-test-com";
        type = text;
    };
}
```

The messages returned are only those which have been sent by that very user for both sides.

For example when I am logged in with "devang-test-com", then this message goes to the else:

```
["name": Devang Agrawal, "id": devang-test-com_abha-test-com_19-Dec-2020 at 7:32:18 PM IST, "sender_email": abha-test-com, "is_read": 0, "type": text, "content": Hello!, "date": 19-Dec-2020 at 7:32:18 PM IST]
```

And when I am logged in as "abha-test-com", the other two messages go to the else:

```
["content": Hello!, "id": abha-test-com_devang-test-com_Dec 19, 2020 at 8:04:34 PM GMT+5:30, "sender_email": devang-test-com, "type": text, "date": Dec 19, 2020 at 8:04:34 PM GMT+5:30, "is_read": 0, "name": Abha Agrawal]

["id": abha-test-com_devang-test-com_Dec 19, 2020 at 8:04:55 PM GMT+5:30, "type": text, "name": Abha Agrawal, "date": Dec 19, 2020 at 8:04:55 PM GMT+5:30, "sender_email": devang-test-com, "content": What is going on ?, "is_read": 0]
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!!

Update: I am confident that the error is because of the dateFormatter which returns nil sometimes. Any Ideas?

Comment: let value = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]

Comment: Hey! I think the real error is that my app is using different date formats. Do you have any idea what to do? Doing what you just suggested gives many errors. If you look at theh date stirng then it is in two different formats. Maybe that is causing the error ? That is when I use simulator they probably use the same date formats and it works?

Comment: Don't use a localized date string as an identifier. A better choice is an UNIX timestamp (seconds since 1/1/1970). Refactor your database model.

Comment: Can you give an example @vadian? Thanks!

Comment: Because the sender object needs Date type as input

Comment: I mean to change the type of `date` in the dictionary – and if possible also in the database – to `Date` and create the `id` with `let id = "devang-test-com_abha-test-com_\(date.timeIntervalSince1970)"`

Comment: yes but when I need to send a Date type object as input. SO is there any way through which I can convert the interval into date?

Comment: [Date(timeIntervalSince1970:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/1780353-init)